# Could not get the display property. Invalid argument

Tags: jquery

i write a jquery code and when i test page in IE 7 i found this Error

Could not get the display property. Invalid argument.

my code:

```
                var $insert = $(item).css({ height: 0, display:'' }).prependTo($list);
                $insert.animate({ height: 35 }, 600).animate({ display: '' }, 600);

                if ($list.children().length > 8) {
                    $list.find('> li:last').animate({ filter: alpha(opacity = 50) }, 600).remove();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing that jumps out at me is that '' is not a valid value for the display property.

Comment: When you set `display` to `''` via the DOM, it is treated as having no inline style value set for that property, it's effectively reset to the default value or the CSS calculated value.  Not sure how it will work in a jQuery animation, though, it could definitely be causing a problem there.